# How can I return from a method also List of transforms or gameobjects without making instances fro new gameobjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public static class TransformSaver
 {
     [System.Serializable]
     public class TransformInfo
     {
         public string sceneName;
         public string name;
         public Transform parent;
         public Vector3 pos;
         public Quaternion rot;
         public Vector3 scale;
     }

     //Save Transform
     public static void SaveTransform(Transform[] tranformToSave)
     {
         TransformInfo[] trnfrm = new TransformInfo[tranformToSave.Length];
         for (int i = 0; i < trnfrm.Length; i++)
         {
             trnfrm[i] = new TransformInfo();

             trnfrm[i].sceneName = tranformToSave[i].gameObject.scene.name;
             trnfrm[i].name = tranformToSave[i].name;
             trnfrm[i].parent = tranformToSave[i].parent;
             trnfrm[i].pos = tranformToSave[i].localPosition;
             trnfrm[i].rot = tranformToSave[i].localRotation;
             trnfrm[i].scale = tranformToSave[i].localScale;
         }

         string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(trnfrm, true);
         File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt", jsonTransform);
     }

     //Load Transform
     public static Transform[] LoadTransform()
     {
         string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt");
         if (jsonTransform == null)
         {
             return null;
         }

         TransformInfo[] savedTransforms = JsonHelper.FromJson<TransformInfo>(jsonTransform);
         GameObject[] gameObjects = new GameObject[savedTransforms.Length];
         Transform[] loadedTransforms = new Transform[savedTransforms.Length];

         for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; i++)
         {
             SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(savedTransforms[i].sceneName));

             gameObjects[i] = new GameObject();
             loadedTransforms[i] = gameObjects[i].transform;
             loadedTransforms[i].name = savedTransforms[i].name;
             loadedTransforms[i].parent = savedTransforms[i].parent;
             loadedTransforms[i].localPosition = savedTransforms[i].pos;
             loadedTransforms[i].localRotation = savedTransforms[i].rot;
             loadedTransforms[i].localScale = savedTransforms[i].scale;
         }
         return loadedTransforms;
     }
 }
```

The problem is that the method LoadTransform will return array of Transforms but also will create new GameObjects in the Editor in the Hierarchy.

What I want to do is to add something like a boolean flag or maybe other way so I can select if toe return the array of transforms with or without creating new gameobjects so I tried something like that:

```
 //Load Transform
     public static Transform[] LoadTransform(bool returnInfo)
     {
         string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt");
         if (jsonTransform == null)
         {
             return null;
         }

         TransformInfo[] savedTransforms = JsonHelper.FromJson<TransformInfo>(jsonTransform);
         GameObject[] gameObjects = new GameObject[savedTransforms.Length];
         Transform[] loadedTransforms = new Transform[savedTransforms.Length];

         for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; i++)
         {
             SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(savedTransforms[i].sceneName));

             if (returnInfo == true)
             {
                 gameObjects[i] = new GameObject();
                 loadedTransforms[i] = gameObjects[i].transform;
             }
             loadedTransforms[i].name = savedTransforms[i].name;
             loadedTransforms[i].parent = savedTransforms[i].parent;
             loadedTransforms[i].localPosition = savedTransforms[i].pos;
             loadedTransforms[i].localRotation = savedTransforms[i].rot;
             loadedTransforms[i].localScale = savedTransforms[i].scale;
         }
         return loadedTransforms;
     }
```

I added a bool flag returnInfo but now loadedTransforms is null.

But the main goal is to decide if to return array of transforms with or without making instances for new gameobjects.

The problem is when I'm using Editorwindow type script and inside OnGUI to save and load the objects:

```
  List<GameObject> selections = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();
          if (selections.Count > 0)
          {
              GUI.enabled = true;
          }
          else
          {
              GUI.enabled = false;
          }
          if (GUILayout.Button("Save selected objects data"))
          {
              if (selections.Count > 0)
              {
                              tempTransformSelection = selections;
                  for (var i = selections.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                  {
                      var selected = selections[i];
                      transformSelection.Add(selected.transform);
                  }

                  TransformSaver.SaveTransform(transformSelection.ToArray());
                  transformSelection = new List<Transform>();
              }
          }

          var file = @"d:\json\json.txt";
          FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

          // By default asume you don't want to show the button
          // it will than only be enabled if the later conditions match
          bool showButton = false;

          // you can check this already here not in the loop
          // if no file -> nothing to do
          if (!File.Exists(@"d:\json\json.txt") || fi.Length <= 0) return;


          // This is only reached if the file exists and is not empty
          // check for null transforms
          for (int i = 0; i < tempTransformSelection.Count(); i++)
          {
              // if not null do nothing
              if (tempTransformSelection[i] != null)
                  continue;

              // otherwise enable the button and leave the loop
              showButton = true;
              break;
          }

          // if not true then button won't be shown
          if (showButton == true)
          {
              GUI.enabled = true;
          }
          else
          {
              GUI.enabled = false;
          }
          if (GUILayout.Button("Instantiate back deleted selected bojects"))
          {
              TransformSaver.LoadTransform(true);
              showButton = false;
          }
      }

      private void OnInspectorUpdate()
      {
          Repaint();
      }
```

The main goal is to select objects in the hierachy in the editor. Then to click on "Save selected objects data" to save the selected object to a json file.

Then I want to make that only if one of the saved objects to the file is null in the hierarchy fro example if I deleted one or more of the objects in the saved file ! only then enable true the button "Instantiate back deleted selected bojects"

And then when clicking on the button "Instantiate back deleted selected bojects" set the button back to enabled false !

But the important thing is to check for null against the saved list of objects in the json file ! But once again I'm stuck with the tempTransformSelection and with how to enable false/true the button.

Comment: Have you tried using a List<Transform>?  The default constructor creates an empty list.

Comment: That's not possible since `Transform` is a MonoBehaviour component and you actually don't return structs or something like that but the references. Afaik you cannot have MonoBehaviour components without attaching them to gameObjects.

Comment: it is not possible to call `new Transform` so i would suggest that your method returns a `List<TransformInfo>` and you adapt your code where you read from this list.